# Error: Expected variable in READ statement at (1)

Tags: fortran, gfortran

I've a code in fortran like:

```
READ( INPUT, 1020 ) ( WK( A + I ), I = 1, NNZA )
```

where:

```
INPUT = 55 (integer)
WK= some data (real)
A and NNZA = some data (integer)
1020 FORMAT( ( 1P, 4D16.8 ) ).
```

But when I try to compile it with gfortran-4.6 I receive an error:

```
READ( INPUT, 1020 ) ( WK( A + I ), I = 1, NNZA )
                   1
Error: Expected variable in READ statement at (1)
```

Does anybody have some suggestion about error?
Thanks!

Comment: Probably best to show us the declarations.

Comment: I'm trying to use the UNCMIN solver with CUTEr problems. Basically, I decode a problem in SIF format, then I call a routine USETUP that "translates" the data for UNCMIN, which will solve the problem. Well, the error becomes when I'm trying to compile the solver. The lines above came from USETUP source.

The declarations can be viewed in these codes:
http://tracsvn.mathappl.polymtl.ca/trac/cuter/export/131/cuter/branches/CUTEr2/common/src/tools/uncma.f

http://tracsvn.mathappl.polymtl.ca/trac/cuter/export/44/cuter/branches/CUTEr2/common/src/tools/usetup.f

Comment: I solved the problem. The variable WK isn't declared, then the error is like in: 

http://www.tek-tips.com/viewthread.cfm?qid=1666999

Thanks for the tips!

Comment: Not related to your error, but the P edit behavior on input is quite strange IMO.  Make sure you read the docs and understand what it does.

Answer (score 0):

I think your error is in the format statement as in

```
1020 FORMAT( ( 1P, 4D16.8 ) ).
```

Shouldn't this just be

```
1020 FORMAT( ( 1P, 4D16.8 ) )
```

Without the final "."? If I remove it, it compiles.