# Error: Expected variable in READ statement at (1) but with declared variables

Tags: fortran, gfortran

This question seems to be related to [Error: Expected variable in READ statement at (1)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20710529/error-expected-variable-in-read-statement-at-1)
but it is not the same, since I have declared the variables.

```
program read_matrix
  integer :: m(3,3),n(3), i, j


  open(1001, file='data1.txt')
  do i = 1, 3
    read(1001,*) (m(i,j), (j=1,3))
  end do

end program read_matrix
```

data1.txt is

```
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9
10
```

I used gfortran to compile the above fortran code, and got

```
read-1.f90:7.16:

    read(1001,*) (m(i,j), (j=1,3))
                1
Error: Expected variable in READ statement at (1)
```

Hence, I am wondering what is the reason for it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your implied-do loop is wrong. Look at the parentheses.  Here what you want

```
read(1001,*) (m(i,j), j=1, 3)
```

Comment: Also note that as you are reading the whole matrix simply Read( 1001, * ) m    is enough

Comment: @ian, it is true one could do the `read` as you have shown, but one needs to be aware of column major vs row major.